# Do wrist supports promote healing for flexor carpi ulnaris tendinopathies?

Tags: tendinopathy, wrist

I read on https://newgrip.com/blogs/wrist-support/newgrip-wrist-support-for-fcu-tendinitis-relief-from-chronic-wrist-pain-and-strain ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170702154245/https://newgrip.com/blogs/wrist-support/newgrip-wrist-support-for-fcu-tendinitis-relief-from-chronic-wrist-pain-and-strain)):

> NewGrip Wrist Support Wraps help eliminate:
>
> - FCU Tendinitis
> - Chronic Wrist Swelling
> - Onset carpal tunnel issues
> - Wrist Hyper-extension

[image]

Do wrist supports promote healing for flexor carpi ulnaris tendinopathies?